# Search bar with array from dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a search bar into my app but ran into some problems.
The data in my Tableview comes from a PLIST and is populated into a NSMutableArray.
My PLIST looks like this and I can also see the data in my array with NSLOG.
Now I want to provide search to my tableview, so that you can search for "name" and the search lists all entries which fit to the entered name. But how can I make my search be able to search all "name" entries?

Update: I have done this but the array stays empty if I start typing in my searchfield.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@",
                                    searchText];

    NSMutableArray *filtered = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

I populate the data into my tableview like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"Rows"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Any my PLIST looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Hot Drinks</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>COFFEE SPECIALS</string>
            <key>Rows</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>3,20 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Espresso</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string></string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>3,20 euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Ristretto</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Short &amp; strong espresso</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>3,50 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Espresso Macchiato</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Espresso with hot milk </string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>4,80 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Espresso Doppio</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Double espresso</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>3,50 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Coffee</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Freshly brewed regular coffee</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>4,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Cappuccino</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Espresso with hot milk and milk froth</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>4,50 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>White Coffee</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>coffee with a lot of hot milk and milk froth</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>4,50 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Latte Macchiato</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Espresso with a lot of hot milk and milk froth, served in a glass</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>0,50 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Flavours of your choice</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Chocolate, caramel, white chocolate, hazelnut </string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>6,50 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Hot “Valrhona” chocolate</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>Hot “Valrhona” chocolate prepared with milk and cream </string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>TEA SPECIALTIES</string>
            <key>Rows</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>English Breakfast – Ceylon / St. James</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>BLACK TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Darjeeling Summer Gold</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>BLACK TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Classic Chai – Indien</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>BLACK TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Assam Barie</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>BLACK TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Earl Grey (Darjeeling)</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>FLAVOURED BLACK TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Dung Ti Oolong – China</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>OOLONG TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Green Dragon</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>GREEN TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Grüner Tee Morgentau</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>FLAVOURED GREEN TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Jasmin Gold</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>FLAVOURED GREEN TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Pai Mu Tan Silver Typ</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>WHITE TEA</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Get the Power</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>FLAVOURED FRUIT INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Red Fruit</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>FLAVOURED FRUIT INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Herbs and Ginger</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>HERBAL INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Original Roibosh</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>HERBAL INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Verbena</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>HERBAL INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Fruity Camomile</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>HERBAL INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Mint &amp; Fresh</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>HERBAL INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Equilibrium</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>FLAVOURED HERBAL INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>price</key>
                    <string>5,00 Euro</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Fruits of Paradise</string>
                    <key>link</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>subname</key>
                    <string>FLAVOURED HERBAL INFUSION</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` for it.

I would suggest following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name contains[c] %@", stringFromSearchField];
```

And you can get filtered array in following way:

```
NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary *dict in myArray)
{
    NSArray *tempRows = dict[@"Rows"];
    if([tempRows isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]] && tempRows.count)
    {
        [rows addObjectsFromArray:tempRows];
    }
}
NSArray *filteredArray = [rows filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

Comment: This works very well. Many thanks. The results are displayed correctly. Is there any chance to display in the searchresults the detailtext of a cell as well? I have put it this way to display in addition to the name the subname   if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"subname"];
        NSLog(@"%@", [[filtered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"subname"]);
    }

Comment: You can display the same data as in original table view. Because filteredArray contains exactly the same objects.

Comment: NSLOG shows the data but they are not display in the result of the search. Only the names.

Comment: The issue is in your cell style.

Comment: Many thanks again. Yes. You were right and I was blind. Sorry.